# Executing cd in a bash function called by subshell causes extraneous output

Tags: terminal, bash

Consider the bash function:

```
func() {
  cd /;
  echo test;
}
```

Calling it does what you'd expect:

```
~:>func
test
/:>
```

But when called from a subshell (eg using backticks or $()) it performs very strangely.

```
~:>func() { cd /; echo test; }
~:>echo $(func)
test Saving session... ...saving history...truncating history files... ...completed.
~:>
```

This issue does not appear if `cd` is not executed in the function:

```
~:>func() { echo test; }
~:>echo $(func)
test
~:>
```

This is causing issues with some scripts that rely on certain output behavior, eg `CLASSPATH=$(func)` where `func` is complex and requires the use of `cd`.

What's strange is that this worked fine before. It did not start to happen until recently, but I don't know what would have caused it.

**Note:** `alias cd` reports "alias: cd: not found" and `which cd` returns /usr/bin/cd which is a script that is identical to another Mac which does not have the problem.

Comment: Looks like the function runs in its own shell somehow. I can't reproduce this here though. Did you change anything in your shell configuration recently?

Comment: Does that come from your `~/.bash_logout`?

Comment: I haven't changed anything recently, but an OS update may have occurred.

Comment: I don't have any ~/.bash_logout either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something odd going on as `cd` is not defined to behave as you are seeing it. Evidence suggests it's definition is being over-ridden somewhere.

It is possible that your `cd` command is aliased somewhere.  The `alias` command with no arguments will display a list of aliased commands on most shells. A workaround for an aliased command is to preface the command with a backslash (`\cd`). That quotes the first letter of the command and defeats any alias processing by the shell.

It is also possible that it is a shell function.  `declare -f` should list the defined functions, at least in `bash`, and you can see if `cd` is being defined as a function.

With luck, your `which` command may support short-cut ways to do these checks.   Check out [this on-line man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) for how one implementation of `which` can be used to check functions and aliases, then see if your `which` operates in a similar manner.

Comment: I tried `\cd` but it had no effect. Note: `alias cd` reports "alias: cd: not found" and `which cd` returns /usr/bin/cd which is a script that is identical to another Mac which does not have the problem.

Comment: gs`cd` should be built into your shell in most every case.

Comment: huzzah: `declare -f cd` results in a script that appears to have been installed by Ruby.

Comment: Ah!  Ruby.  You must be using `rvm` to manage your rubies.  I believe that implementation requires redefinition of `cd`.  Glad you figured it out!